# Different Path Folder vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In case, i'm create function to process excel and in the end of process i want to save excel into my "Download" folder in my pc.. but i get a different folder path between my pc and my server.. when i running my application using my pc, i get path "C:/Users/MyPCUserName/Downloads" but when i running application on published file (iis server), i get path "C:\Users\SYSTEM\Downloads\85FE1000".. I don't know what's the wrong with my code / function..

This my Code :

```
Private Sub myMethod(ByVal pProjectNo As String, ByVal pOrderNo As String)
    Dim dt As DataTable = ClsUploadBreakDownInquiryDB.GetFinalInspectionData(pProjectNo, pOrderNo)
    if dt.Rows.Count > 0
        
    'My Function Here
    
    Dim user As String = System.Environment.UserName
    exl_b2.SaveAs("C:\Users\" & user & "\Downloads\" & pProjectNo & "_" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Format  (Date.Now, "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") & ".xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook)

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't hard code C:, rather have a look at `Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile` and work it out from there.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer i'm already test your suggest but `Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile` not return my user name pc.. also i'm already create string `Dim user As String = System.Environment.UserName`

Comment: Think you might need to re-think the save location.  A web app is going to have some real issue trying to save to a user profile directory such as downloads.

Comment: @Hursey yes, i think this not good for dinamic server

Comment: @Hursey: Why would a web app have problems saving to the Downloads folder? Browsers do it by default. Thanks for helping me understand.

Comment: @MontanaMan Browsers do of course, but server side of web application usually can't do that.

Comment: @Arvo  Thanks ... It's 4:11 am and I've been up all night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save a up-loaded file on your web server quite much any place you want.

However, if you talking about a client side user - and their browswer download lcoation? You have ZERO, but 100% ZERO control over that location.

In fact, the user might be using a iPhone, or Android - and not even a desktop comptuer.

You do not have ANY ability in ANY case to control the location of a user download of a file. Files on the local computer are 100% hands off. When they download, it will usually go to their downloads folder - but the user settings control that.

You can't grab, see, or set ANY file location on the client side computer. I mean, if you could do that, then when you come to my site to view a cat picture? My code would then rummage around on your computer - looking for files called passwords, or files called banking etc and steal them

So, server side code behind? Sure, you can in most cases save the file on the web server computer anywhere you like - it don't matter a whole lot.

However, if you talking about client side computer locations for the user and their browser hitting your web site? No, you have zero information, zero control over the users files, and even where they choose to save, or download such files - that is their computer - and browsers give protection for reasons of security.

This can sometimes be confusing when using Visual Studio during development, since your computer, your browser and your web site are all running on the ONE SAME computer, but in a typical deployment, that of course is not the case. So, code behind has zero knowledge about the users local file system.

As a result, you cannot grab, or set ANY kind of file location information on the client side computer.

So, saving to "users" with code behind is ONLY going to apply to the code behind web server "user", and has nothing to do with the client side user.

As a general rule, any and all folders you work with and use from code behind? In EVERY case that should be a sub folder of your root of your project.

Keep in mind:

```
Any markup code - urls - that is relative to your web site

Any code behind - plane jane windows path name.
```

So, if you add a folder to your project, it might be say folder UpLoadFiles.

So, then web based, mark up based will be like this:

```
https://localhost:44392/UpLoadFiles/doc.pdf
```

So, UpLoadFiles is simple a sub folder in your project.

However, in code behind, your code ALWAYS works with plane jane valid windows file names. So, to convert above to a plane jane file path in windows? You do this:

```
    Dim strFile As String = Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadFiles/abc.txt")

    Dim strText As String = File.ReadAllText(strFile)
```

At this point, now str file is a plane jane valid full good old fashioned windows file name.

So, code behind = always plane jane window path name

So, web markup and URL = always a relative path from your project root.

```
dim strTextFile  = File.ReadAllText(strFile).
```

Comment: Thanks for your information sir, i'm get a new knowledge